Time Travel Manwha About a VR Game
About a year ago, I started reading a manwha where a character was a high-level player in a VR game, but travels back in time to just after the start of the game before all the secrets were found.  I think he was a thief-type class.
I remember in his first mission in the past, he completed a quest to get to the top of a mountain in a time-limit, and he did it by bouncing off a monster's head using a skill, and got a secret class and armor from an old-man/hermit NPC.  Then he lead a group to clear a swamp-based S-class dungeon by aggroing the boss and having the team pelt it with moltovs.
Does any of this ring any bells?

Does this include the game world mixing with reality? About half of the time rewind+virtual reality stories I'm seeing involve that. Does the protagonist die and reincarnate in the past, or just go back in time?

I found it. The Game That I Came From, aka Ultimate Rogue's Awakening or Wo Laizi Youxi.

Tianyong Land is a game where players can get their powers in real life and become an awakened. Ling Ce is an orphan who steps into a glitch in the game, sending him three years back into the past. Determined to change his destiny, Ling Ce uses his experience to be the first and strongest awakened.


Hey, it's great that you found it.  Could you add a synopsis and maybe a link so people can read a bit about it?  And don't forget to accept your answer.
